# Regex to validate url contains culture code

Tags: c#

I am using one web application where i am taking current url which contains culture code.

There are two url patterns where i have to validate culture code.

First pattern:

```html
var url = "http://localhost:1469/en-US";
```

Second pattern:

```html
var url = "http://localhost:1469/somepagename/en-US";
```

Please suggest me some regex that will validate url contains culture code or not.

Comment: That's basic regular expression for a url

Comment: The question doesn't indicate any effort on your part.  Show us what you've tried and we'll help you, but we won't do it *for* you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to answer your question, you can try something like this:

```
string pat = @"[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}"; 
Regex regex = new Regex(pat);

var url1 = "http://localhost:1469/en-US";
var url2 = "http://localhost:1469/somepagename/en-US";
Console.WriteLine(regex.Matches(url1)[0]);
Console.WriteLine(regex.Matches(url2)[0]);
```

Comment: @FirstOrGoad, This solution is working fine for me. Thanks for helping me. I am upvoting your solution.